# Getting the selected country from the database into select box

Tags: php, mysql, select

Hi all and thanks for your time.

I'm using the following query to get information from my database:

```
$sql = "SELECT amember_countries.country, amember_countries.title, gold_profile.username, gold_profile.country AS userCountry 
        FROM amember_countries 
        LEFT JOIN gold_profile
        ON amember_countries.country = gold_profile.country

        ORDER BY amember_countries.title ASC
        ";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);

$selected = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    if ($row['userCountry'] == $row['country'] && $row['username'] == $username){
    $selected = "selected"; 
    }else{
    $selected = "";

    }
    echo "<option ".$selected." value=\"".$row['country']."\">".$row['title']."\n "; 
}
```

It works fine, but the problem I'm facing is if 3 people are from the Netherlands, the select box will show 3 times Netherlands. Same thing for the rest of the countries.

So for example:

```
user 1 is from The Netherlands
user 3 is from The Netherlands
user 6 is from The Netherlands
```

When clicking on the select box it shows:

```
Belgium
Canada
Luxemburg
Netherlands
Netherlands
Netherlands
```

The same thing is happening to the other countries.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could potential solutions to this:

**Code Side**

You could do something like this:

```
$a = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    if ($row['userCountry'] == $row['country'] && $row['username'] == $username){
    $selected = "selected"; 
    }else{
    $selected = "";

    }
    if(!in_array($row['country'], $a))
    {
       echo "<option ".$selected." value=\"".$row['country']."\">".$row['title']."\n "; 
       array_push($a, $row['country']);
    }
}
```

**Database**

You could also tailor your database query to simply select the countries:

`SELECT * FROM FROM amember_countries GROUP BY amember_countries.country`

...Or something to that effect.

I would personally suggest the database solution as that would be the "correct" solution (databases are made to solve this kind of problem).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your first solution worked like a charm. Can you please explain what you mean with your second solution?

Comment: The second answer is essentially the same thing as @mu's answer (his is a little more detailed :))

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to do two things at once with one query:

1. Get all the countries from `amember_country`.
2. Get `gold_profile.country` for `$username`.

You'll have better luck if you grab the information for `$username` first and then do this to get the country list:

```
$sql = "SELECT country, title 
        FROM amember_countries
        GROUP BY country, title
        ORDER BY title ASC
        ";
```

The GROUP BY will collapse duplicates.

Then you'll need to update your `while` look to use the country for `$username` rather than `$row['userCountry']` to figure out the selected option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Won't that show only the country the user has chosen? In example user 1 it will show only Netherlands, and not the rest of the countries? The user must be able to edit the countries if he wants.

Comment: The SQL will pull out all the distinct countries from `amember_countries`. You would grab user's country from `gold_profile` with a separate query.